# inclusion complemented spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I need help for the following question. If $X$ is a normed space with two complemented decompositions: $X = M \oplus N$ and $X = P \oplus Q$, where $M, N, P, Q$ are closed subspaces. If $N \subset Q$, then is it true that $P \subset M$?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $N=Q=\mathbb{R}e_1$, $P=\mathbb{R}e_2$ and $M=\mathbb{R}(e_1+e_2)$.

Comment: Very clear example. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I was initially very convinced that the assertion was true so I spent about two hours tryibg to prove it, hehe